# How to output relationship between entities to if-then diagrams?

Tags: python, nltk, chunking

I am trying to extract chunk patterns using NLTK and I have 2 groups of patterns.One of them is input and the lead to the second group.Example:

```
<PRP><MD><VB><DT><NN><IN><DT><JJ><NN>
```

with an example like: you may sell the house on a single trial

and

```
<IN><JJ><NN><MD><VB>
```

with an example like: if hard try would benefit

are two groups of what I want to extract.Then I need to draw the second pattern as the input to the first pattern as a diagram.Is there any way to to this in python? I am looking for something like this automatically extracted from the two groups of patterns.

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. What do you mean "draw" a pattern? Like a parse tree? It's confusing because the English sentences aren't grammatical.

Comment: @erip I have edited my question :)

Comment: While I appreciate the edit and time you took to make the above image, I don't understand how the two sentences related. _if hard try would benefit_ doesn't make sense in English, nor does selling a house _on a single trial_.

Comment: @erip: Sorry for my bad examples.you can think of 2 expressions that one of them leads to the other.It does not matter what the sentence or expression is.what I need to know is how is it possible to connect two regexpressions like the image above

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you would like to draw shapes and connections between shapes in MS Visio. I don't know of any way to write Visio-files directly with python without reverse engineering the file format yourself, but you can do it through the "COM Interface" of Microsoft's Office programs. You would need Visio installed as what you would basically be doing is controlling Visio through a python script. Here is a short example of how to make a new document:

```
import win32com.client
visio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
visio.Visible = 0
doc = visio.Documents.Add('')
# Do stuff...
doc.SaveAs('C:\\Users\\Alma\\diagram1.vsx')
visio.Quit()
```

Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee861526.aspx is a good place to start looking for how to do things. It's documentation for VBA but the interface is the same for python, and the documentation is quite thorough. I have only ever used this to read information *from* Visio-documents but if you read the documentation I am sure you can figure out how to create shapes as well.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.I really don't look specifically for visio connected solution.I was thinking there must be drawing packages for python that can draw a relationship between phrases/sentences.

Comment: @alma you got to change the title of the question then =)